# Populate column in dataframe based on iat values

Tags: python, pandas

```
lookup={'Tier':[1,2,3,4],'Terr.1':[0.88,0.83,1.04,1.33],'Terr.2':[0.78,0.82,0.91,1.15],'Terr.3':[0.92,0.98,1.09,1.33],'Terr.4':[1.39,1.49,1.66,1.96],'Terr.5':[1.17,1.24,1.39,1.68]}
df={'Tier':[1,1,2,2,3,2,4,4,4,1],'Territory':[1,3,4,5,4,4,2,1,1,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
lookup=pd.DataFrame(lookup)
```

lookup contains the lookup values, and df contains the data being fed into iat.

I get the correct values when I print(lookup.iat[tier,terr]). However, when I try to set those values in a new column, it endlessly runs, or in this simple test case just copies 1 value 10 times.

```
for i in df["Tier"]:
    tier=i-1
    for j in df["Territory"]:
        terr=j
        #print(lookup.iat[tier,terr])
        df["Rate"]=lookup.iat[tier,terr]
```

Any thoughts on a possible better solution?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Can you include it in your post?

Comment: the desired output is listed in print(lookup.iat[tier,terr]), I just want those values mapped to df["Rate".

Comment: `df['Rate'] = lookup.iat[tier,terr]` is going to set the entire column to the last looked up value.  I copy and pasted exactly what you have and now have a df with the rate column equal to 0.92 for everyone.

Comment: I know, I mentioned that.

Comment: What we both mean is that you should post your correct desired output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` after some modification to your `lookup` dataframe:

```
lookup = lookup.rename(columns={i: i.split('.')[-1] for i in lookup.columns}).set_index('Tier')
lookup.columns = lookup.columns.astype(int)

df['Rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: lookup.loc[x['Tier'],x['Territory']], axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
   Tier  Territory  Rate
0     1          1  0.88
1     1          3  0.92
2     2          4  1.49
3     2          5  1.24
4     3          4  1.66
5     2          4  1.49
6     4          2  1.15
7     4          1  1.33
8     4          1  1.33
9     1          2  0.78
```

Comment: Perfect, can you explain why you renamed the columns? that part throws me off. As well as what exactly is x["Tier"],X["Territory"] doing?

Comment: I renamed the columns so that you can query them by number (instead of `Terr.1`, `Terr.2`, etc.), and `lambda x: x['Tier']` w/ `axis=1` allows you to apply the lookup row-wise, where `x` corresponds to each row.

Answer (score 1):

Once `lookup` modified a bit the same way than **@rahlf23** plus using `stack`, you can `merge` both dataframes such as:

```
df['Rate'] = df.merge( lookup.rename(columns={ i: int(i.split('.')[-1]) 
                                               for i in lookup.columns if 'Terr' in i})
                            .set_index('Tier').stack()
                            .reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Territory'}),
                       how='left')[0]
```

If you have a big dataframe `df`, then it should be faster than using `apply` and `loc`

Also, if any couple `(Tier, Territory)` in `df` does not exist in `lookup`, this method won't throw an error